# uploading image rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, rails-activerecord

I am new to rails and so I decided to start studying doing exercises according to a book, but its for rails 3 so no surpsise some things dont work with rails 4. I was trying to build simple image uploader according to the code from the book ( no need to tell me how easy it can be doing it the other ways )
So I have a view :

```
<%= form_for(@person, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|  %>
<% if @person.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this person from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><% xxx=msg.split %>
        <% xxx.shift %>
        <%= p xxx.join(" ")%>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :secret %><br>
<%= f.password_field :secret %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<p>
<%= f.label :country %><br />
<%= f.select :country, [ ['Canada', 'Canada'],['Mexico', 'Mexico'],['United Kingdom',    'UK'],['United States of America', 'USA'] ]%>
</p>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :description %><br>
<%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :can_send_email %><br>
<%= f.check_box :can_send_email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :graduation_year %><br>
<%= f.number_field :graduation_year %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :body_temperature %><br>
<%= f.text_field :body_temperature %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :price %><br>
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :birthday %><br>
<%= f.date_select :birthday %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :favourite_time %><br>
<%= f.time_select :favourite_time %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :photo %><br />
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

a part of the controller for creation :

```
    def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @person.save
    format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
    else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
    end
    def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :secret, :country, :email, :description, :can_send_email, :graduation_year, :body_temperature, :price, :birthday, :favourite_time)
end
```

And the part of model:

```
    after_save :store_photo


     private

    PHOTO_STORE = File.join Rails.root, 'public', 'photo_store'

    def store_photo
    if @file_data    
FileUtils.mkdir_p PHOTO_STORE
File.open(photo_filename, 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(@file_data.read)
    end    
   @file_data = nil
   end
    end
   def photo=(file_data)
   unless file_data.blank?   
  @file_data = file_data
self.extension = file_data.original_filename.split('.').last.downcase
    end
    end


    def photo_filename
    File.join PHOTO_STORE, "#{id}.#{extension}"
    end
    def photo_path
    "/photo_store/#{id}.#{extension}"
    end
    end
```

But it doesn't work, I know I probably need to add "photo" to permitted params but when I do it gives me an error, because I dont have such an attribute in my DB, I have only "extension" for uploaded images' extensions because file names will be = ID's like "24.jpg". I think I need to permit "photo" parameter and still be able to create a new person ( like adding "photo" as an exception or something but I have no clue how to do that and if that's the case). Anyway, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add "photo" to permitted params, or it will not be put in the model.

Then move "photo=" above "private", because if "photo=" is a private method, Rails will not be able to find attribute "photo"

```
def photo=(file_data)
    unless file_data.blank?
        @file_data = file_data
        self.extension = file_data.original_filename.split('.').last.downcase
    end
end

private

........
```

Comment: Yeah it was all about "private" thing, foolish of me. Thank you very much.